# Localstorage with images

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I would like to save an image url in the localstorage of html5 and then would like to set that image on a web page and also set a link to another webpage (that link addres is also in the localStorage) But how can I do that

Update1: Is it possible without base64?

Comment: why do you need to store the URL in localStorage? what does newImage() do?

Comment: Using [Chrome](http://google.com/chrome) you can use the **Resources** section of the **Developer tools** to view the contents of `localStorage` and much more. This might help you debug your application and determine what's going wrong. In terms of the `localStorage` API try looking at [Mozilla's excellent documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage). Also, I'm guessing `newImage()` should be `new Image()` but you will also need to append the created `Image` to another element somewhere in the document in order for it to be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yep you are doing it wrong!

#### You need something like this using image in base64:

```
<script>
var hero;

if (localStorage.getItem('heroImg')) {
    hero = localStorage.getItem('heroImg');
}
else {
    hero = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7    /.../    6p+3dIR//9k=';
    localStorage.setItem('heroImg', hero);
}

document.getElementById("hero-graphic").src = 'data:image/png;base64,' + hero; < /script>

</script>
```

#### The corresponding HTML Image element:

```
<img id="hero-graphic" alt="Blog Hero Image" src="" / >
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, nowadays, the only reliable way to store binary data in localStorage - is to keep base64-encoded string. But you should keep in mind that localStorage is limited, and images can be heavy (and base64 makes them heavier).

I guess you are trying to cache your images. It would be better in almost all cases just to set properly http headers, to let the browser do all the dirty and tedious work for you. Trust me, it is way better.